Flink sql IS JSON returning true, but unable to get key data
I have a valid flink sql select '"{\"id\": \"38b5eed2-5d42-4cb9-8f75-2df56665b44b\"}"' IS JSON, JSON_VALUE('"{\"id\": \"38b5eed2-5d42-4cb9-8f75-2df56665b44b\"}"', '$.id');, not able to get id value, above sql returning null.
